# Create csr_matrix to be used in k-medoids

Tags: python, csv, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I am trying to use k-medoids PAM algorithm. The data which to be clustered is formed in a 2D matrix and stored in a csv file. How to read the csv data into a csr_matrix.
I wrote the following code but it did not give me a matrix. Instead I get a list of lists.
In addition, how to create the csr_matrix from normal matrix **data** to be passed to k-medoids algorithm.

```
datafile = open('...\\DisMatrix_Drug.csv', 'r')
datareader = csv.reader(datafile, delimiter=';')
for row in datareader:
   data.append(row)
# Code to create scr_matrix
data1 = 116
l = []
for i in range(data1):
    l.append((i for x in range(data1)))
row_ind = np.array(l)
col_ind = np.array(l)
data2 = np.array([c for c in data], dtype=float)
mat_coo = sparse.coo_matrix((data2, (row_ind, col_ind)))
```

Unfortunately, I get the following error message:

> Error at line: mat_coo = sparse.coo_matrix((data2, (row_ind,
>   col_ind)))
>
> TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'generator' and
>   'generator'

How to solve this error?

Comment: Look at `l`.  It should be a 1d array of integers, or equivalent list

Comment: Practice making some small sparse matrices before jumping into this bigger task.

Comment: If `data` is already a list or iterable, `[c for c in data]` doesn't add anything.  `np.array(data)` should be enough.  `l.append([i for _ in range(data1)])` should avoid the generator problem.  `l` will then be a list of lists.  But `data2`, `row_ind`, `col_ind` should all be 1d arrays of the same size.  If `row_ind` and `col_ind` are the same, you'll just be setting the main diagonal.